# Decomposing an iPhone user interface -- multiple views in one xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, nib, xib

I have one main view with an associated controller. I have some rather complicated toolbars that I need to switch in and out depending on user interaction.

To keep things simple I manage the toolbars with my main view controller, rather than having all sorts of intertwined dependencies or really deep delegate chains.

Anyway, how can I have multiple views in one xib and initialize them properly? Like if I want to display one of my custom views in the center of the screen, how would I do that?

Alternatively, if I separate the views into multiple xibs, how can I have them reference the same controller object for their IBOutlets/IBActions?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726250/nsviewcontroller-and-multiple-subviews-from-a-nib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyway, how can I have multiple views
>   in one xib and initialize them
>   properly? Like if I want to display
>   one of my custom views in the center
>   of the screen, how would I do that?

You can have as many `UIView`s as you want in your xib. Usually you'll make one the "primary" view -- the one that's hooked up to the File Owner's view property (i.e. your view controller) -- and the rest can sit in the xib at the same level. You can hook them up to other properties in the view controller as well.

You could make these views as *subviews* for the main view. (Few, that's a lot of view). Let's say you have two views, `FooView` and `BarView`. You want `FooView` to be present at startup. So you just set `BarView` to be hidden in IB. Then your view controller might look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    FooView* fooView;
    BarView* barView;
    ...
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet FooView* fooView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet BarView* barView;
...
```

Then, inside your code, when you want to change views, just use the `setHidden:` method to hide one and show the other.

> Alternatively, if I separate the views
>   into multiple xibs, how can I have
>   them reference the same controller
>   object for their IBOutlets/IBActions?

You can have other xibs sharing the same view controller. I've done it lots myself. Just set the File Owner to the appropriate class.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple.  You just create a new root-level view in your XIB file and create an `IBOutlet` for this view in your main view controller.

As far as loading views directly from XIB's, sharing the same view controller, that's a little more sloppy.. you'd essentially need to loop through the items in the XIB file and find the element you're looking for.

Comment: I've done this, but I haven't dragged my BarView into the MainViewController, so it doesn't show up. How can I display it?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out, had to add it as a subview. Thought I had tried that to no success, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note from this approach is that *all* the views get initialized when any of the views are needed.

If your views are simple this might not matter, but if you have complex views, this might make your application slow to load.

If the views are somewhat complex, you should split them into different `.xib` files. In this case the parent `UIViewController` would have IBOutlets to the other `UIViewController` subclasses rather than IBOutlets to `UIViews`. The view controllers will automatically handle the lazy-loading of their respective views.