# How to add subview in ListView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am developing my first MAC application, i downloaded one Example of  [PxListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7mp2.png)

and i have to added one button and background image on cell xib and bind them with controller 
and, when on button click i was set height of that cell is much bigger then other. that is done,
and work fine.

but now i want to develop like after is witch cell has open in that cell i want to add some extra contain (Controller) on it, so how it will possible using given example?
pls help me to give some suggest how it will be done.
for Ex like before click on button
[image]

after chick on button i want to develop like

[image]

Comment: Your second paragraph isn't clear. Do you have a button that makes one of your list views get larger? Is that already working? Would you post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You write**

> i have to added one button and background image on cell xib and bind them with controller

It sounds like you've subclassed `PXListViewCell`--for convenience, let's call your subclass `TemplateListViewCell`--and added a `xib` from which instances of `TemplateListViewCell` will be loaded in

```
+[PXListViewCell cellLoadedFromNibNamed:bundle:reusableIdentifier:]
```

In addition, there is a[t least one] button in `TemplateListViewCell.xib`.

**You write**

> when on button click i was set height of that cell is much bigger then other. that is done, and work fine

It sounds like this button has as its action a method on `TemplateListViewCell` such as

```
- (IBAction)toggleDetail:(id)sender
{
    //Code to grow or shrink the height of [self frame].  
    //...
}
```

In my approach to implementing `-toggleDetail`, two modifications to the `PXListView` files were necessary:

`1.`  Adding a protocol method

```
- (void)listView:(PXListView *)aListView setHeight:(CGFloat)height ofRow:(NSUInteger)row;
```

to the `PXListViewDelegate` protocol.

`2.`  Adding a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL expanded;
```

to `PXListViewCell`.

My implementation of `-toggleDetail` looks something like this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleDetail:(id)sender
{
    BOOL wasExpanded = [self expanded];

    NSRect oldFrame = [self frame];
    CGFloat oldHeight = oldFrame.size.height;
    CGFloat newHeight = oldHeight;

    CGFloat heightIncrement = 0.0f;
    if (wasExpanded) {
        heightIncrement = -80.0f; //use whatever value is appropriate
    } else {
        heightIncrement = 80.0f;  //use whatever value is appropriate
    }
    newHeight += heightIncrement;

    [[[self listView] delegate] listView:[self listView] setHeight:newHeight ofRow:[self row]];
    [[self listView] reloadData];

    BOOL isExpanded = !wasExpanded;
    [self setExpanded:isExpanded];
}
```

It might seem better to use `[[self listView] reloadRowAtIndex:[self row]];` in place of `[[self listView] reloadData]`, but unfortunately, this doesn't work: if the user hides the detail--shrinks the cell vertically--new cells which should appear on the screen do not.

**You write**

> that is done, and work fine.

It sounds like you were able to implement successfully a method analogous to `-[TemplateListViewCell toggleDetail:]`.

**You write**

> but now i want to develop like after is witch cell has open in that cell i want to add some extra contain (Controller) on it, so how it will possible using given example? pls help me to give some suggest how it will be done.

It sounds like you want instances of `TemplateListViewCell` to contain extra views if they are expanded.

It might seem tempting to put this code into `-[TemplateListViewCell toggleDetail]`, but this will not work out as we might hope.  The trouble is, we need to handle cases where expanded cells have been scrolled out of view and scrolled back into view.

To get this right, we need to have a notion of expanded which persists beyond the usage of a `PXListViewCell` subclass instance: we either need to keep track of expansion in the `PXListView` itself or in its delegate.

The better--but less expedient--design seems to be to keep track of this information in the `PXListView` itself.   For the sake of this question, however, I'll demonstrate how to keep track of cell expansion in the delegate.  To do this, I'm expanding the `PXListViewDelegate` protocol and making other changes to the `PXListView` files:

`1.`  Adding the methods

```
- (void)listView:(PXListView *)aListView setExpanded:(BOOL)expanded atRow:(NSUInteger)row;
- (BOOL)listView:(PXListView *)aListView expandedAtRow:(NSUInteger)row;
```

to `PXListViewDelegate`.

`2.`  Adding the method

```
- (void)setCell:(PXListViewCell *)cell expandedAtRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(listView:expandedAtRow:)]) {
        [cell setExpanded:[[self delegate] listView:self expandedAtRow:row]];
    }
}
```

to `PXListView`.

`3.`  Calling `-[PXListView setCell:expandedAtRow:]` from `-[PXListView layoutCells]`

```
- (void)layoutCells
{   
    //Set the frames of the cells
    for(id cell in _visibleCells)
    {
        NSInteger row = [cell row];
        [cell setFrame:[self rectOfRow:row]];


        [self setCell:cell expandedAtRow:row];


        [cell layoutSubviews];
    }

    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    CGFloat documentHeight = _totalHeight>NSHeight(bounds)?_totalHeight:(NSHeight(bounds) -2);

    //Set the new height of the document view
    [[self documentView] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, NSWidth([self contentViewRect]), documentHeight)];
}
```

and from `-[PXListView layoutCell:atRow:]`:

```
- (void)layoutCell:(PXListViewCell*)cell atRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    [[self documentView] addSubview:cell];
    [cell setFrame:[self rectOfRow:row]];

    [cell setListView:self];
    [cell setRow:row];
    [cell setHidden:NO];

    [self setCell:cell expandedAtRow:row];
}
```

`4.`  Setting `_expanded` to `NO` in `-[PXListViewCell prepareForReuse]`:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    _dropHighlight = PXListViewDropNowhere;
    _expanded = NO;
}
```

*Note*: In [the sample `PXListViewCell` subclass, `MyListViewCell`,](https://github.com/Perspx/PXListView/blob/master/Classes/MyListViewCell.m) distributed with `PXListView`, the implementation of `-[MyListViewCell prepareForReuse]` fails to call `[super prepareForReuse]`.  Make sure that this call is made in `[TemplateListViewCell prepareForReuse]`:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    //...
    [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

One change needs to be made to `-[TemplateListViewCell toggleDetail:]`.  The line

```
[self setExpanded:isExpanded];
```

needs to be replaced by

```
[[[self listView] delegate] listView:[self listView] setExpanded:isExpanded atRow:[self row]];
```

Once you've set up your `PXListView`'s delegate to properly handle the new delegate methods, you're ready to override `[PXListViewCell setExpanded:]` in your subclass `TemplateListViewCell`:

```
- (void)setExpanded:(BOOL)expanded
{
    if (expanded) {
        //add detail subviews
    } else {
        //remove detail subviews
    }
    [super setExpanded:expanded];
}
```

Replace `//add detail subviews` with your own code which programmatically adds the detail subviews that you want and replace `//remove detail subviews` with code to remove the detail subviews that you want, checking to see that they are present first.

**You write**

> i want to add some extra contain (Controller) on it

It sounds like you want to add view *controllers* rather than views to your `TemplateListViewCell`.  To do this, use an `NSBox` and set the box's `contentView` to your view controller's `view`.  (For details on this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617947/1052673).)

If you plan on just showing a single view controller's view in an `NSBox` on the expanded `TemplateListViewCell`, you can just (1) add a property to `TemplateListViewCell` referencing your view controller and (2) add an `NSBox` to `TemplateListViewCell` xib and set its `contentView` to the appropriate view controller's view on `[cell setExpanded:YES]` and set its contentView to `nil` on `[cell setExpanded:NO]`.