# Cocoa : Load NSViewController with nib

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, nib, osx-mountain-lion, nsviewcontroller

I have tried many possibilities I found on this site and read some explanations 
from apple developer page, but seems like i couldn't resolve my problem about
loading NSViewController with/form NIB.

Files on Xcode Project look a bit like this :

- SecondViewController.h
- SecondViewController.m
- SecondViewController.xib
- AppDelegate.h
- AppDelegate.m
- MainMenu.xib

The main problem is how could i create the SecondViewController programatically with
the initial nib on SecondViewController.xib

> - Custom class of FileOwner on MainMenu.xib is NSApplication
> - Custom class of FileOwner on SecondViewController.xib is SecondViewController
> - There are some panels and window in MainMenu.xb (about window and preference panel)
> - This application has no main window (using notification icon on status bar)

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : NSViewController {
    BOOL fullScreenMode;
    NSImageView *fullScreenbg;
    NSImageView *imageView1;
    NSImageView *imageView2;
    NSPanel *imageWindow;

}


@property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView *fullScreenbg;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView1;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageView2;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPanel *imageWindow;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController {
    NSImageView *nv1;
    NSImageView *nv2;
    NSSize curImgSize;
}

@synthesize fullScreenbg;
@synthesize imageView1;
@synthesize imageView2;
@synthesize imageWindow;

......

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        fullScreenMode = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSWindowDelegate> {
   NSPanel *aboutWindow;
   IBOutlet NSMenu *myStatusMenu;
   IBOutlet NSMenuItem *toggleFullScreen;
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    SecondViewController *controller;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
                 initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" 
                 bundle:nil];  
    //Not work (fullscreenbg, imageView1, imageView2,imageWindow = nil)

    //controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; ?? <-- didn't work either
}
```

Even if using initWithNibName or just init, all the IBOutlet properties seems to be nil
on debug.

i've tried other solustions like "NSBundle loadNibNamed" or [using loadView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726250/nsviewcontroller-and-multiple-subviews-from-a-nib) but it didn't work (warning message : "NSObject my not respond to loadView").

The main purpose of the secondViewController is to display notification message including
graphics and web element.

I hope someone could give me a best suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint during your NSViewController's initialisation and see if you're actually initialising it or not.

Comment: Sure. The initialisation on appdelegate executed, initwithnibname at second controller executed, controller is not nil/null but all controller outlets are nil/null.

Comment: Only outlets?  Are you manually setting the outlets?  If you are, try set them in awakeFromNib instead.

Comment: I got it, add [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self]; before the line [super initWithNibName .......]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. IBOutlets are not connected in the constructor.

You can override viewDidLoad, call super and then do any initialization.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    //added this line :
    if (nibBundleOrNil!=nil || ![nibBundleOrNil isEqualtoString:@""]) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self];
    {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        fullScreenMode = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct answer, which would also give you 15 rep.